# Send SMS to multiple contacts

Tags: android, sms, contacts, message

I want to send SMS at once to multiple contacts.
The second thing I want is to use the phone's regular SMS service and not to get a window where I need to select the program (i.e. select between SMS, Whatsapp, Skype and so on).

I am using this very short code:

```
    numbers = "050-1234567;051-1234567;052-1234567";
    String message= "this is a message";

    Uri sendSmsTo = Uri.parse("smsto:" + numbers);
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, sendSmsTo);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", message);
    startActivity(intent);
```

It is not working. I get opened only the last number in the 'numbers' string and not to all of them.

What am I doing wrong?

The two questions are:

1. How to send SMS to all the numbers in the string?
2. How to pass automatically the 'select service window' and simply use the default SMS service built-in every phone?

Thanks!
AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For multiple contact using array and [SmsManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html) to use SMS Service:

```
String[] numbers = new String {"46654","4654","16548"};

for(int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
    smsManager.sendTextMessage(numbers[i], null, "Text Message", null, null);
}
```